# Reboot not required for .NET 4.0 after VS2012 runtime installation

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My WPF application was running fine when built on VS2010 and using WiX3.5. I changed to VS2012 and installed the VS2012 runtime using Wix as below:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
   <Merge Id="VC110RedistCRT" SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC110_CRT_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
   <Merge Id="VC110RedistMFC" SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC110_MFC_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
 </DirectoryRef>

 <Feature Id="VC110Redist" Title="Visual C++ 11.0 Runtime" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1">
   <MergeRef Id="VC110RedistCRT"/>
   <MergeRef Id="VC110RedistMFC"/>
 </Feature>
```

Earlier with VS2010, application installation on new machine used to ask for reboot while installing .NET framework. Now with VS2012, it doesn't ask for reboot and application is running fine also.

I just wanted to know the possible reason and any side effects of this. Any details of how the C++ runtime and .Net Framework installation work with each other will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Those entries have nothing to do with the .NET Framework.  They are the runtime files you'd need for a native C++ app built by VS2012.  A million miles away from a WPF app.  Given the low odds that they are already present and used by a running process, there's nothing unusual about not having to reboot.  Whatever .NET version you need, if you in fact install it (don't), it is probably already available on the machine.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for reply. I do have bootstrapper for .Net 4 in wixproj file